# Trying to create a rock, paper, scissors game to be played in console. Having trouble with displaying the first if condition in the console

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console.log

I'm trying to set up a simple rock, paper, scissors game to be played in the console and I'm having trouble with the first if condition not displaying anything.

This is the if statement

```
if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "rock") {
    console.log("It's a tie!")
}
```

When both playerSelection and computerSelection equal "rock" there is no console.log message.

Here is the whole code:

```
//create variable for each object
const getComputerChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

//select one variable randomly
const computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
getComputerChoice.length);
console.log(getComputerChoice[computerSelection]);

//create prompt
const playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");


//player selection is rock
if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "rock") {
    console.log("It's a tie!")
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `computerSelection` is still a number. You should use better variable names, calling an array of three strings `getComputerChoice` is going to cause problems, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Your `computerSelection` isn't a `string` it's an index of type `number`.

Either convert it to the correct value or remember to check it in the if statement.

### Option 1

```
const getComputerChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

const computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
getComputerChoice.length);

const playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

if (playerSelection === "rock" && getComputerChoice[computerSelection]) === "rock") {
    console.log("It's a tie!")
}
```

### Option 2

```
const getComputerChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

const computerSelection = getComputerChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
getComputerChoice.length)];

const playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection) === "rock") {
    console.log("It's a tie!")
}
```